# Function called successfully from update statement but gets error when called from select statement

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE plch_test
(
   x   NUMBER
 , y   VARCHAR2 (3)
);

BEGIN
   INSERT INTO plch_test
        VALUES (1, 'NO');

   INSERT INTO plch_test
        VALUES (2, NULL);

   COMMIT;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION silly_function (p_x NUMBER)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   l_y   plch_test.y%TYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT t.y
     INTO l_y
     FROM plch_test t
    WHERE t.x = silly_function.p_x;

   RETURN l_y;
END;
```

What will I see on the screen after running the following block?

```
BEGIN
UPDATE plch_test SET y = 'YES' WHERE silly_function (x) != 'YES';  -- Line 2 Function call
 select silly_function(x) from dual; -- Line 3
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Updated=' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN VALUE_ERROR
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('VALUE_ERROR');
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('OTHER_ERROR');
END;
/
```

I thought line 2 and line 3 would throw error `X: invalid identifier`. But, when I executed above script line 2 executed and line 3 threw an exception. Can anyone explain the difference between line 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0):

Line 2:

```
UPDATE plch_test SET y = 'YES' WHERE silly_function (x) != 'YES';
```

... will update one row in your table, the one that had `y` set to `'NO'`. The other row is null so isn't equal to, or not equal to, anything. The `x` is a valid identifier because you are referring to table `plch_test`, which has a column with that name. The function is called for each row, with that row's value of `x`.

Line 3:

```
 select silly_function(x) from dual;
```

... will error because you are not selecting into anything, which of course you have to do in a PL/SQL context. But you also don't have an `x` variable in scope, so it would still error.

So this won't error (hopefully; untested):

```
DECLARE
  l_x plch_test.x%type;
  l_y plch_test.y%type;
BEGIN
  UPDATE ... ;
  l_x := 1;
  select silly_function(l_x) into l_y from dual;
END;
```

You aren't helping yourself by catching and squashing the actual exception you're getting, otherwise this would have been pretty obvious.

You also don't need a select here, as you can just do an assignment:

```
  l_y := silly_function(l_x);
```

---

After your comments and verifying with a test, the update you said worked doesn't, as it throws `ORA-04091: table SCHEMA.PLCH_TEST is mutating, trigger/function may not see it`. Your update is deciding what value to give `y` based on the current value of `y`. But what does 'current value' mean in the middle of an update statement? Which value of `y` is Oracle supposed to use with in the select inside the function - the pre-update or post-update value? The exception is effectively saying that it can't safely and consistently choose, so you're asking it to do something unsafe and inconsistent, which an RDBMS really tries to avoid.

One way around that is to separate the query/function call from the update, e.g. with a cursor for loop:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c IS
    SELECT * FROM plch_test
    WHERE silly_function (x) != 'YES'
    FOR UPDATE;
BEGIN
  --UPDATE plch_test SET y = 'YES' WHERE silly_function (x) != 'YES';
  FOR r IN c LOOP
    UPDATE plch_test SET y = 'YES' WHERE CURRENT OF c;
  END LOOP;
END;
/

anonymous block completed

SELECT * FROM plch_test;

         X Y 
---------- ---
         1 YES
         2
```

Comment: But, apparently line 2 throws `mutating error` and won't update any row. Thanks for pointing out to use `INTO` clause when using `select`. I used `select silly_function(x) into y from dual;` and got same error (invalid `X` identifier). I know, same thing can be done, which you wrote at the end. But, I just wanted to know why same function called didn't work when calling from `select` ?

Comment: @jWeaver - the function didn't work from the select because you didn't have an `into` clause, and you seem to still not have a variable called `x`. That's why I defined and used a `l_x` variable. Why are you now talking about mutating tables - you get that issue in triggers, not an anonymous block, which is what you have shown.

Comment: Please execute above block. I have executed above block and seen error.

Comment: @jWeaver - OK, I was concentrating on the select. You said the update worked in the question, but it's that which gets the mutating table error. Updated with a workaround, though that wasn't what you originally asked about.

Comment: my question was, when I comment `line 2` then  `select silly_function(x) into y from dual;` throws error `X : invalid identifier` whereas commenting out `line 3` the `update` statement works. And when I say working, which means I'm not getting `invalid identifier` error instead, I'm getting mutating error. That means function was called from `update` statement. correct ? Then question arise why did update throws exception instead of `invalid identifier` error ? We are calling same function with same argument.

Comment: @jWeaver - I already covered that in my answer. It isn't the same argument. In the update you're calling the function with the `plch_test.x` column value, which *is* a valid identifier. In the select the `dual` table does not have a column called `x`, and you don't have a local PL/SQL called `x` either, so that identifier is not valid. My block, using an `l_x` I defined, does not get that exception?